# Response description and POST parameters in API Blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

I am trying out API Blueprint and found some things, which are not quite clear to me.

### 1. How can I document POST body parameters?

There is `+ Parameters` but it just documents query parameters. If I now want to describe a POST API I can't document POST parameters (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). The same goes for JSON (see #3).

### 2. Is there a way to add a description to a response?

I tried

```
+ Response 403
If the request request is made with HTTP instead of HTTPS.
```

But this just adds the text as the body response.

### 3. Describe the different fields of my response

If I return JSON I want to describe each field separately, its type and its purpose. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets look #1 and #3 together as they are closely related:

## Description of payload fields

Currently there is no dedicated syntax for discussing the actual fields of a [payload](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-payload-section) (model, response or request).

For now it is up to you how do you describe it using any Markdown syntax you like.

The plan is to provide a Markdown syntax for discussing these fields / parameters like this:

JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"]
}
```

and its description in blueprint:

```
- id: 1 (integer) - The unique identifier for a product
- name: A green door (string) - Name of the product
- price: 12.50 (number)
- tags: home, green (optional, array of strings)
```

I am currently working on this. More details can be found [here](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/25#issuecomment-40098651).

## Response description

You can already add any markdown [formatted discussion to a payloads](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#example-3)

```
# Resource [/r]
## List [GET]
+   Response 200

    This response will list the R

    + Body

            { ... }
```

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19433269/634940

Note: In order for the description to appear correctly in Apiary you might need to use the [New Apiary Rendered documentation](http://blog.apiary.io/2014/03/20/Re-API-Design-for-Humans/)

Comment: Note: If your response have empty body but you still need the description there you need to append `+ Body` without any content. This is the unfortunate tradeoff for the abbreviated body syntax

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible that for #2 the comment is only shown, if there is a mime type? Your example will not show a comment (at least when I tried it), but only if I add the mime type.

Comment: Nope that should not be needed. I have just tested it and it works good - see http://docs.desctest.apiary.io, please send email to support@apiary.io if it does not work for you (note make sure you have "New Documentation" turned on in settings)

Comment: I spent like 4-5 intense hours browsing the full Blueprint lang spec and the apiary website trying to answer exactly the same questions as the OP - how to specify a request parameter. It is 2019 - 5 years since this answer was posted and now it turns out that there is still no way of specifying a request parameter!!! Yes, an API documentation tool that has no concept of request parameters.