# Document POST request with API blueprint and Apiary

Tags: api, apiblueprint, apiary

I am documenting a service with API endpoints which need to be accessed with a POST request in `application/x-form-urlencoded` format with Apiary. The issue is, no matter how much I looked, I could not find any mention of that, or any sort of reference to it.

I only found this [6 year old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735745/response-description-and-post-parameters-in-api-blueprint), but it seems to be outdated

How do I describe a POST request with a URL encoded form in Apiary